# Is a rain of alcohol possible?

Tags: atmosphere, chemistry

For a story I am planning, I'd like to have some planets with unusual atmospheric phenomena. One of the ideas I have are alcohol rains.

I know that Titan has methane clouds and methane rain. Would it be possible for a planet or moon to have atmospheric precipitation of methanol, though? I'm asking because chemistry was never my forte.

As a side question, would it be possible for such precipitation to happen with other kinds of alcohol too/instead, such as ethanol and isopropanol?

This question differs from [Atmospheric isopropyl alcohol](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/169546/21222) because that one is just about the presence of isopropanol in the atmosphere, whereas here I am focusing on precipitation.

Comment: If you have liquid oceans of some substance you will almost always also have clouds and rains of that substance... Liquids evaporate, the vapor goes in the atmosphere, accumulates and eventually condenses. (More contrived cycles can be imagined, but they would have to be really sneaky.)

Comment: @AlexP I understand that methanol and ethanol boil and condense like water does, just at different temperatures. I wonder if such a cycle could exist with them, or if they would break up into other substances or become trapped into rocks.

Comment: Not any more than water... The vast majority of Earth's water *is* trapped in rocks as water of crystallization, or as plain infiltration of liquid water. The point is that Earth has sufficient water so that part of it is not trapped in rocks, and forms oceans. If you have oceans of a liquid substance, *any* liquid substance, you will also by necessity have vapor of that substance in the atmosphere. Sufficient vapor in the atmosphere plus non-uniform heat distributions leads to condensation, and clouds, and rain. The key point is having oceans of that substance in liquid state.

Comment: It's likely for it to exist somewhere. We already know of comets like Lovejoy releasing ethyl alcohol and several gas clouds containing ethyl alcohol or methyl alcohol.
Plus if you consider the fact that we believe it can rain glass, rubies, diamonds, and other stuff like that on other planets, alcohol doesn't sound so unlikely.

Comment: A world you can get high for just breathe? where i can buy a ticket?

Comment: Is there oxygen in the atmosphere?

Comment: @cowlinator I hadn't considered that, and Slarty's answered covered scenarios with and without it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Whilst theoretically possible in practice it would not happen. Alcohols like ethyl alcohol are too chemically reactive to remain stable in a planetary environment in large quantities for very long. Any oxygen from the atmosphere would oxidise it to acetic acid. Other alcohols suffer a similar issue.

Alcohols can also be transformed by a range of other substances like acids to form esters. They can be dehydrated in arid conditions to form alkenes and undergo many other reactions, so unless the planet is a featureless waste of glass with an inert atmosphere the alcohol is likely to react with its surroundings.

Comment: Methane and ethane and much *more* reactive than methanol or ethanol, and yet [Titan has entire seas of them](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lakes_of_Titan)...

Comment: @AlexP Titan has no oxygen for methane and ethane to burn in.

Comment: @JohnDvorak: Yes, and? Is free oxygen common in the atmospheres of various planets? You can equally say that Earth has no fluoride for water to burn in.

Comment: Ethanol and alcohols in general are more reactive than methane and alkanes. Methane only contains C-H bonds, but ethanol contains C-O and O-H bonds as well as C-H bonds so is susceptible to a wider range of reactions. I can probably find some reference if anyone doubts that alcohols are more reactive than alkanes. Fluorine is a highly reactive substance and will react with almost anything. Both methane and ethanol will react with it so it is not a good example. A better example would be something that reacts with methane but doesn’t react with ethanol.

Answer (score 4):

## Absolutely

Alcohol can evaporate, which then rises. And evaporated alcohol can condense into a liquid and fall back down. This process is at the heart of making spirits. The diagram below ([source](https://serc.carleton.edu/details/images/46246.html)) shows this process.

[image: Distillation process diagram]

Now here's a diagram of the water cycle on Earth ([source](https://www.noaa.gov/education/resource-collections/freshwater/water-cycle)):

[image: Water cycle diagram]

Fundamentally, both processes use the same scientific principles. As long as your planet can generate the conditions necessary to evaporate and condense the given liquid, you can have that liquid rain onto the surface.

EDIT: To clarify, you might need some hand waving to make this work, but it's plausible enough that you can include it in sci/fi without needing a ton of explanation.